# SQL Server table only one Active Record at a given time

Tags: sql-server, non-clustered-index

I have a SQL Server 2016 table where only one record should be active at any given time. There will be CRUD operations to it.

I am trying to create a unique nonclustered index on that table so that it has only 1 active record at any time. Criteria for active record is if today's date is between `StartDate` and `StopDate`. ID is a unique key. For the rest, I am not sure if my syntax and strategy is correct.

Here is my SQL:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[GWFO_FlashNewsItem]
(
    [ID] [INT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Title] [VARCHAR](150) NOT NULL,
    [NavigateToURL] [VARCHAR](250) NULL,
    [StartDate] [SMALLDATETIME] NOT NULL,
    [StopDate] [SMALLDATETIME] NULL,
    [Active] [BIT] NOT Null,
    [UpdateSOEID] [CHAR](7) NULL,
    [UpdateDate] [SMALLDATETIME] NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_GWFO_FlashNewsItem] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
                    WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                          IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                          ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX uixf_GWFO_FlashNews_Active_filtered
ON GWFO_FlashNewsItem (Active)
INCLUDE (ID, Title) 
WHERE Active = 1
```

Comment: I'm pretty confident you can't create a filtered index based on the current date. (I'm not in a position to check, but it would make no sense, as the rows in the index would be forever changing).

Comment: @Larnu, That is correct, deterministic clauses only.

Comment: Any other solution you can suggest? For eg adding another bit Column 'Active' and during INSERT/UPDATE operation set it accordingly. And apply an index to it?

Comment: Why are you converting your smalldatetime to a string to make comparisons? Aside from this not working as you are trying that is effort wasted. Just compare the smalldatetime values. For the task at hand why do you need a filtered index? Just create a view with top 1 with the ordering logic.

Comment: A Trigger will allow you to check any criteria you want on every update to the table.

Comment: Can you add a check constraint instead?

Comment: This kind of manipulation screams of being an xy problem to me.

Answer (score 0):

From the context it seems as if you are attempting to limit a record from being inserted or updated that contains a date range that is not in the current date.  In order to do that you could use a trigger.  If the date range does not meet your criteria of being active you can raise an error and prevent the insert or update from occurring.

I also just tried creating a check constraint and that works as well:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[test]
(
    [d1] [DATETIME] NULL,
    [d2] [DATETIME] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[test] WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [CK_test] CHECK ((GETDATE() >= [d1] AND GETDATE() <= [d2]))
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[test] CHECK CONSTRAINT [CK_test]
GO
```

This code:

```
INSERT INTO test SELECT '1/1/2000', '1/1/2001'
```

Throws this error:

> Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 24
>   The INSERT statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "CK_test". The conflict occurred in database "SysproSupport", table "dbo.test". The statement has been terminated.

Ultimately though it seems that you should be able to control the types of records that you are manipulating with your front end.  If you have an application or data entry interface that is manipulating your data, you can put these constraints into it.  Implementing this as a constraint or trigger will ensure not even an administrator can clean data without disabling them.

Comment: Will give your suggestion a shot

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to identify more clearly what you need first. For example, you have a record with Active bit set, StartDate is today 0:00:00, StopDate is today 23:59:59, everything is fine.

Until it's 23:59:59, when your condition (Active bit should be set only when GetDate() is between StartDate and StopDate) is not valid anymore. What do you think should happen at that second? That bit magically converted to 0, just by itself?

Another question, should your requirements allow records to have Active set to 0 even if the condition is satisfied? If the answer to this question is "no", then your active bit is not separate field, but simply a [non-deterministic] function of StartDate and StopDate, and your only concern is to not allow overlapping intervals.